# Simple script doesn't show anything on the Output in LuaEdit

Tags: lua, lua-edit

I've just started learning Lua by my own. I'm working with LuaEdit And I can't test this simple script:

```
print (5)
```

Nothing shows on the output. Please help.

Aditional info:

I'm following this tutorial http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/Mathe.php. And it told me to download LuaEdit from this address http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaedit/. However, the editor on the tutorial has a lot more options than the one I downloaded, I don't know if that has anything to do with it, also when I add an error:

```
print (5)
{
```

it does shows an unexpected symbol Syntax Error, so at least I know it's trying to run... or is it? please help. Why doesn't anything show on the Output window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your Lua file is saved and debugging is stopped.
2. Click the green start debugging button.
3. The output pane should appear.  Make sure the drop down menu inside of the pane that says "Show output from" has "Lua" selected.

Comment: Thank's, that was it. "Lua" wasn't selected. What a rookie mistake. Cheers!