# luaedit 3..0.10 will not show output from simple script

Tags: lua, luainterface, lua-5.2, luarocks, lua-edit

I am trying to get output from my first script in luaedit 3.0.10 and not having much success.  I'm using the sample script from the online tutorial at http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/Mathe.php  to wit:

```
a = 2 + 1
print (a)
```

I'm running luaedit under windows vista, and have unpacked the lua binaries but can find no way to link luaedit to them, and thus assume that luaedit includes a lua runtime as part of itself.

There is a similar question already posted in these forums, but the answer does not work for my version of luaedit.  The answer refers to a pane in the "show output from" window that does not appear in my version of luaedit.  My version only has an "output" window that is accessible off of the "debug" drop-down menu.  Though it does say show output from, there does not appear to be any way to change where it shows its output from.  The answer also refers to a green button to start debugging that is also not available in my version of the editor.  Instead, there are three buttons on the left side of the toolbar:  a triangular "start debugging" button, a double horizontal line "break now" button" and a square "stop debugging" button, all of which are blue.

So...how is the problem to be solved for THIS version of this editor?  Or is it a bug that the developers introduced because they had to fix an interface that wasn't broken?

Comment: A link to the "similar question already posted in these forums" that you are referring to might be helpful

Comment: Happy to oblige:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853382/simple-script-doesnt-show-anything-on-the-output-in-luaedit